# Issue of character spacing in Preview of Report Viewer in RDLC Report

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access-2010, rdlc

I got the issue of character spacing in RDLC report viewer preview window as below [image]image.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

How to increase the character spacing?

Thanks

Comment: Choose different font maybe?

Comment: @initknit, I alreary tried this solution but same issue still exists.

Answer (score 2):

change your resolution to 1024X768 and restart your application it works